# SQL syntax or database constrictions?

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I have 2 tables that have each a column `MNR`. I want to join them with this column.

The following two SQL statements fail. The last one shows that my date format is working (with changed session format). DB is Oracle.

**Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong ?** And what do I call this join ?

```
// fails
select a.CREATEDATE, a.BELEGNRRECH, a.MNR, a.UTNR, a.KTXT, b.ANR
from INFOR.RELFBR as a, INFOR.RELXDB as b
where (a.SAINT = '90') and (a.MNR = b.MNR) and (b.SAINT = '10')
     and (a.CREATEDATE >= '01.01.2014 00:00:00')
order by a.CREATEDATE

// fails as well
select a.CREATEDATE, a.BELEGNRRECH, a.MNR, a.UTNR, a.KTXT, b.ANR
from INFOR.RELFBR as a, INFOR.RELXDB as b
where (a.SAINT = '90') and (a.MNR = b.MNR) and (b.SAINT = '10')
order by a.CREATEDATE

// all fine
select CREATEDATE, MNR
from INFOR.RELFBR
where (CREATEDATE >= '01.01.2014 00:00:00')
order by CREATEDATE
```

**Failing error is `ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended`**
After removing "order by ..." same error occurs.

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: Fails.... with which error?

Comment: @BobJarvis I'm using C# to get the data. An exception is thrown displaying this error message. No, I don't get any rows.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Exclude AS from table aliasing - AS can be used with selection list but not in FROM clause

```
select a.CREATEDATE, a.BELEGNRRECH, a.MNR, a.UTNR, a.KTXT, b.ANR
from INFOR.RELFBR a, INFOR.RELXDB b
where (a.SAINT = '90') and (a.MNR = b.MNR) and (b.SAINT = '10')
     and (a.CREATEDATE >= '01.01.2014 00:00:00')
order by a.CREATEDATE
```

Example:

```
SQL> select * from t_dummy t;

                      X                                                         
-----------------------                                                         
                 9.0000                                                         

SQL> select * from t_dummy as t;
select * from t_dummy as t
                      *
error in line 1:
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
```

Documentation:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_10002.htm#i2126863

Comment: Wow, I was sure I've used `AS` in `FROM` somewhere. But I was wrong. I couldn't find anything. спасибо!

Comment: Now I see why I made that mistake: [from with as on w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp)